# xlsx to csv (including format whole column AND replace empty cells in specific column)

Tags: powershell

I would like to have powershell comand to do the following - but I do not have the skills to figure it out :-)

Ideal:
Input "file.xlsx"
Output "file.csv
(If its too much trouble csv to csv is fine)

1. Set the cells with empty dates in column "Date" to 'xxx'
2. To format/replace the column Date's characters from "." to "-"
3. set (if needed) -Encoding utf8

[image]

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say *"csv to csv is fine"*, here's what you can do if you have exported the Excel file to Csv first:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\file.csv' -UseCulture | 
    Select-Object Firm, Code, 
                  @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {
                      if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Date)) { 'xxx' }
                      else { $_.Date.Replace('.', '-') }
                  }} |
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\new_file.csv' -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>I'm using switch `-UseCulture` so both Import-Csv and Export-Csv will user the same delimiter character your Excel uses</sup>

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for your comment. From the question it was not clear what the real column headers were.

There is an extra issue with header `'Fulde navn'`. Because it is explicitely single quoted in the Excel file, when saving this as CSV, the header in the CSV becomes `Fulde navn'`. As you can see, the first single quote is removed by Excel, but the closing quote remains.

You can fix this by either removige these quotes around the header in Excel before saving as CSV, or by listing that header in the code as `"Fulde navn'"`.

In the edited code below, I use that (although I would prefer removing the quotes in the original Excel file).

To keep the characters `æøå`, we also need to force Excel to export UTF8 and the only way I found was to save it as `Unicode Text (.txt)`, which creates a TAB delimited file with a .txt extension.

In Excel, choose `Save As...` and select file type `Unicode Text (.txt)Unicode`:

[image]

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\inputfile.txt' -Delimiter "`t" | 
    # Excel leaves a trailing single-quote for header 'Fulde navn' ..
    Select-Object 'Virksomhedskode', 'Afdelingskode', 'Kode', "Fulde navn'", 
                  'Stillingsbetegnelse', 'CPR-nummer', 'Bogføringsgruppekode',
                  @{Name = 'Fratrædelsesdato'; Expression = {
                      if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Fratrædelsesdato)) { 'xxx' }
                      else { $_.Fratrædelsesdato.Replace('.', '-') }
                  }}, 'Ansættelsesdato' |
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\new_file.csv' -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation
```

---

---

**EDIT 2 (the final version)**

```
$Path = 'D:\Test\file.xlsx'

Write-Host "Converting file '$Path'"

# convert the Excel file to a temporary TAB-delimited Unicode file
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false 
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Activate()

# Excel up to and incuding version 2016, has no option to export csv format
# in UTF8 encoding so we save as Unicode Text (*.txt)
# this in fact is a Tab-delimited csv file, normally called '*.tsv', '*.tab' or simply '*.csv'

# as of Excel 2019, you can try $xlCSVUTF8 = 62

$xlUnicodeText = 42  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat
# save to a file with the same path and name, but a different extension
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, '.tab' )      
$workbook.SaveAs($tempFile, $xlUnicodeText) 
$workbook.Close()
$excel.Quit()

# important: cleanup used COM objects
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

Write-Host "Creating new CSV file '$tempFile'"

# read the exported .tab file, adjust the 'Fratrædelsesdato' field and
# save as true CSV file in UTF8 encoding
Import-Csv -Path $tempFile -Delimiter "`t" -Encoding Unicode | 
    Select-Object 'Virksomhedskode', 'Afdelingskode', 'Kode', 'Fulde navn', 
                  'Stillingsbetegnelse', 'CPR-nummer', 'Bogføringsgruppekode',
                  @{Name = 'Fratrædelsesdato'; Expression = {
                      if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Fratrædelsesdato)) { 'xxx' }
                      else { $_.Fratrædelsesdato.Replace('.', '-') }
                  }}, 'Ansættelsesdato' |
    Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\new_file.csv' -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

# you can now delete the temporary tab-delimited file
Remove-Item $tempFile
```

Comment: Thanks. But I seem to have a problem with my characters æøå is shown with "?" both with utf8 and other formats. And I have these headers in the colomns (including æøå), so it cannot get the data.

The right headers are:
**Virksomhedskode, Afdelingskode, Kode, 'Fulde navn', Stillingsbetegnelse, CPR-nummer, Bogføringsgruppekode, Fratrædelsesdato, Ansættelsesdato,**

_Fratrædelsesdato_ is = 'Date' 

If I try to correct the headers to none æøå it seems to work? Any solutions to fixing this?

Comment: @KasperM Please see the edit in my answer. There were two Excel related issues to fix.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear. The Header 'Fulde navn' is not quoted in the xlsx report. I just did that when I run the powershell command. Sorry

Saving a txt file seem to be a step more I am affraid. And the report is auto generated, so if we need to open the file and save to txt, we could just save the file to csv after small replacements in excel?  Or do I miss something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @KasperM No, saving to `Unicode Text (.txt)` **IS** saving as CSV, but that is the only way Excel will save as UTF8. The only difference with a 'regular' csv is that the fields are separateb by a **TAB** character, not a comma. For PowerShell, that is no trouble at all. Excel is known for its lame import/export functionality. Everyone would prefer to be able to export with a self-chosen delimiter character and in a self-chosen encoding, but helas, Excel is what it is..

Comment: @KasperM I have edited the answer again and put in code to automatically convert directly using the .xlsx file. This way you don't have to save the Excel file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Code right now:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\input.csv' -UseCulture |  

Select-Object 'Virksomhedskode', 'Afdelingskode', 'Kode', 'Fulde navn', 'Stillingsbetegnelse', 'CPR-nummer', 'Bogføringsgruppekode', 'Ansættelsesdato',
                  @{Name = 'Fratrædelsesdato'; Expression = {
                      if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Fratrædelsesdato)) { 'xxx' }
                      else { $_.Fratrædelsesdato.Replace('.', '-') }
                  }} |

Export-Csv -Path 'D:\edited.csv' -UseCulture -Encoding utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```